# xrdp to ubuntu with Gnome

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, xrdp

**EDIT**

I have an Ubuntu 19.04 machine and a Windows 10 machine. Want to xrdp from Windows 10 to Ubuntu with Gnome session. Tutorials I've seen online describe how to do it with xfce4. Looked everywhere for a guide on how to do it wit Gnome but couldn't find it. So the question is how do I xrdp to Ubuntu with Gnome session?

**EDIT**

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/175700) but I can't figure out a command to start gnome

Comment: Maybe this helps https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/1723

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still a bit vague to me and I dont have enough points to ask in the comments for clarification.

Though,

`gnome-session` should start gnome. This is what I've used in the past. However this was for Gnome2 days. With Gnome3 I abandoned ship after short usage, so it is probably different.

Alternatively if you only have  one configure DE, you may get away with 
`startx`

Comment: I provided more details